# Using a URL to launch a link that is within a Facebook App Iframe?

Tags: html, facebook, iframe

I read other threads and I'm not even sure if I titled this correctly. My apologies.

My IFRame Facebook app has "View Details" buttons and when clicked, it opens up the "correct page" inside the iframe.

If I right-click on any "View Details" button and open a new window and go to that URL the button is linked to, I am taken outside of the Facebook Iframe and to the website, the app is originating from.

How do I create a web URL that will open up Facebook and go directly to "View Details" link?

```
1- https://www.facebook.com/CarDealerChatbots
2- Click Vehicle Inventory on left
3- Right-click View Details button on the right
4- Copy Link
5- Click on any "View Details" button
```

Comment: May you be a little more clear? What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: @SilvioBiasiol Please see OP and thanks.

Comment: You would have to change the link to something like `https://www.facebook.com/CarDealerChatbots/app/1829162920689523/?app_data=something` where you set something to what you need to show the right thing

Comment: @WizKid Okay, I will investigate further.